# Does the application server JBoss include CXF installation?

Tags: eclipse, cxf, jboss7.x

I'm trying to set the CXF Runtime on Eclipse web services preferences window.
I'm trying to point to JBoss installation in my pc at : 
C:\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\cxf

But I'm getting error : Missing CXF jar: Please select the CXF home directory.
Shouldn't JBoss include a working CXF installation ?

Answer (score 1):

Jboss AS 7.x have the dependency for apache CXF, you can use that by loading the module  in your web application. There are a lot of way to achieve this on of common is setting apache cfx module as global module which will loaded into memory as the application server will started. Add the following lines in standalone.xml of jboss server-

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >
  <global-modules>
  <module name="org.apache.cxf" slot="main" />
  </global-modules> 
  </subsystem>
```

If you want to add the module as web application dependent then you can use jboss-deployment-structure.xml-

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.apache.cxf" services="import">
            <imports>
               <include path="**" />
            </imports>
         </module>
      </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and if you are using the maven build the you can load the module by manifest entry for the dependency-

```
<build>
   ...
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <archive>
             <manifestEntries>
                <Dependencies>org.apache.cxf</Dependencies>
             </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thank you .My question was about why I'm getting error when trying to set the CXF Runtime on Eclips web services preferences window. Can I understand from that error that JBoss doesn't have a full instalation of CXF ?

Comment: CXF is a type of JAX-WS implementation, another approaches are JAX-WS AXIS and JAX-WS JBOSS WS implementation.     
So JBOSS doest not have the full intstallatin or say the implementation 
for CXF.

Comment: you can download CXF installation and set that as CXF home then go in Preferences->WebServices->server and runtime and set the server with AS which you are using and runtime as CXF runtime.

After that you right click on project  go on Properties->Project Facets and checked the check box for Apache CXF then select the runtime (Jboss) which you have setup for CXF in prefernce, apply and all wil work for you.

Comment: yes sure I can . My concern is about compatibility . I prefer to develop with CXF version that is being included already with my runtime environment (jboss 7.1) . So I thought I can count on jboss CXF module but it seems I can not . so what will be the best approach to avoid compatibility issues ?